# Custom font not showing on my web preview

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, custom-font

The problem: 
- Downloaded webfontkit from font squirrel 
- added the fonts to a new css file with font family, src, font-weight, font-style 
- tried to apply it to my header 
- checked my web browser, font changed to a default font but not the custom font I wanted

Things i've tried 
- reexamined my code a few times 
- downloaded the webfontkit again with other formats .ttf and .svg 
 **index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first-->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- build:css css/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <title>DEVEDAN: A Digital Marketing Agency</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--I hid the Navbar code because it was irrelevant-->

<!--WEBSITE CONTENT-->      
    <!-- Page content holder -->
<div class="page-content p-5" id="content">

    <!-- Heading -->
    <h2 class="display-4 text-white">DEVEDAN</h2>
    <p class="lead text-white mb-0">Develop your business w/ Edson & Angelika</p>
    <div class="separator"></div> 

</div>
    <!--I hid the jscode because it was irrelevant-->
</body>
</html>
```

**fonts.css file**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'siffonOutline';
    src: url('fonts/siffonoutline-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/siffonoutline-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/siffonoutline-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/siffonoutline-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/siffonoutline-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/siffonoutline-webfont.svg#sifonnbasic_outline') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**styles.css file**

```
/*Fonts*/
@import "fonts.css";

/*NAVBAR*/
.vertical-nav {
    min-width: 17rem;
    width: 17rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.page-content {
    width: calc(100% - 17rem);
    margin-left: 17rem;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

/*WEBSITE CONTENT*/
h2 {
    font-family: 'siffonOutline';
}

body {
    background: #599fd9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #599fd9, #c2e59c);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #599fd9, #c2e59c);
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.separator {
    margin: 3rem 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
}
```

Click link to view the output of my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePLCh.png]

Comment: Have u check the @font-face path? Is this font folder correct?

Answer (score 0):

check @import path is rite or wrong

@import "fonts.css";